# Plotting for solution for $y=x^2$ and $x^2 + y^2 = a $

Tags: graphing-functions, functional-equations

Consider the system $$y=x^2$$ and $$x^2 + y^2 = a $$for $x>0$, $y>0$, $a>0$.

Solving for equations give me $y+y^2 = a$, and ultimately $$y = \frac {-1 + \sqrt {4a+1}} {2} $$ (rejected $\frac {-1 - \sqrt {4a+1}} {2} $ since $y>0$).

The next part is to plot on the $x-y$ plane for different values of $a$. Is plotting the graph of $y = x^2$ insufficient?

Comment: First plot the parabola $y=x^{2}$, then plot the semicircle $y = sqrt(a-x^{2})$ which lies above $x$ axis. You'll get $2$ points of intersection.

Comment: @Hyperbola $x>0$, so only one point

Comment: Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is insufficient.

You should notice that this equation is "special:"
$$x^2 + y^2 = a$$
This is the graph of a circle, radius $\sqrt{a}$.

So, your graph should contain both the parabola and the part of the circle in the region in question.

Here's a [link to a graph from Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%7Bx%5E2%2by%5E2%20=%201,%20x%5E2%2by%5E2=4,%20x%5E2%2by%5E2=9,%20y=x%5E2,%20x%3E0,%20y%3E0%7D) which may help give some intuition.  The darkest shaded region that is there is the region of interest.